# SQL Query Exercise Oracle 18c

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to resolve this exercises:

> Visualize the actors who have had more than twice the compensation of the media of their compatriots.

- FILM (CODFILM,TITLE,YEAR,GENRE) --Year is NUMBER, it contains only the Year
- ACTOR (CODACTOR,NAME,SURNAME,NAZIONALITY)
- CAST (CODFILM,CODACTOR, COMPENSATION).

I've tried this solution, but it doesn't works

```
SELECT CODACTOR
FROM ACTOR NATURAL JOIN CAST T
WHERE COMPENSATION >(
SELECT AVG(COMPENSATION) * 2
FROM ACTOR NATURAL JOIN CAST
WHERE NAZIONALITY = T.NAZIONALITY)
```

> Select, for each actor, the year in which he / she played the first and last films by viewing the results in descending order based on the latter value.

```
SELECT CODACTOR, MIN(YEAR), MAX(YEAR)
FROM FILM NATURAL JOIN CAST T
GROUP BY CODFILM, CODACTOR
HAVING CODACTOR IN (
SELECT CODACTOR
FROM CAST
WHERE CODFILM = T.CODFILM)
```

This last exercise I don't know how to resolve because I don't have Date Of Birth column.

> Visualize the roles in which French actors born before 1990 have never played. (Suppose that exist the column BIRTH, type DATE.)

Comment: How will you calculate the age of the actor, if you haven't got a date or birth column. How do you know when they are born?

Comment: you can not name your table CAST, because it is a keyword in ORACLE, therefore the  SELECTS do not work

Comment: For future reference, NATURAL JOIN falls into that category of things which just because we can do them doesn't mean we should do them. NATURAL JOIN is suspect, because subsequent model changes can alter the behaviour of our code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below for your first query

```
    SELECT A.codactor
    FROM   actor A
    inner join cast C
    ON A.codactor = C.codactor
    WHERE  compensation > (SELECT trunc(Avg(compensation)) * 2
                   FROM   actor A1
                          inner join cast C1
                                  ON A1.codactor = C1.codactor
                   WHERE  A1.nazionality = A.nazionality

                              )
```

For your second query please try the below

```
  WITH films
 AS (SELECT c.codfilm,
            c.codactor,
            F.title,
            F.year,
            F.genre
     FROM   film F
            inner join cast c
                    ON c.codfilm = F.codfilm)
   SELECT A.codactor,
   Min(F.year) FIRST_YEAR,
   Max(F.year) LAST_YEAR
          FROM   actor A
          inner join films F
           ON A.codactor = F.codactor
           GROUP  BY A.codactor
```

Comment: The first one run, but it doesn't shows me any row.
The second can't run because FILM doesn't have CODACTOR field

Comment: i have edited the first and second query ,try now,also post sample data for the tables

Comment: Thanks, they works. I can't give you a positive vote, because i'm new. Do you think that i need to post the sample?

Comment: you can accept the answer so that others may benefit

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
SELECT a.CODACTOR, count (c.*) 
FROM ACTOR a
     , CAST c 
where a.nazionality = c.nazionality 
group by a.CODACTOR having count(c.*)> 2
```

Comment: Nazionality is presents only in Actor and oracle show me a problme with count (c.*)
"invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Comment: Yes that is your problem, you don't have referencing coumns in all your table, so it is not possible to find actors in cast and you also can not find actors in film. There need to be one coulumn in table actor which is the same in table cast and so on

Comment: But this columns should be CODACTOR, CODFILM in CAST witch connect FILM and ACTOR

Comment: ``SELECT a.CODACTOR, count (*) 
FROM ACTOR a, CAST c where a.codactor = c.codactor 
group by a.CODACTOR having count(*)> 2``

Comment: But this shows me only how many times an actor played in a film. This isn't the answer of any of my questions

Comment: Given that the Seeker has posted queries using ANSI 92 join syntax it is poor that you have chosen to use the older and generally deprecated implicit join syntax.